# Compare sign of two doubles

Tags: visual-c++, floating-point, double, sign

What's the fastest way to compare sign on a `double`?

I know that a `double` has a "sign bit" but I'm not sure if the way I'm "looking for it" in its binary rep is a good idea or not.

Barring "portability" issues, can someone tell me what's going on with this code in MSVC++?

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
  double z = 5.0 ;

  __int64 bitSign ;

  __int64 *ptr ;

  ptr = (__int64*)&z ;

  for( __int64 sh = 0 ; sh < 65 ; sh++ )
  {
    bitSign = 1L << sh ; // Weird.  it doesn't do 1.
    printf( "Bit# %d (%llx):  %lld\n",
      sh, bitSign, ( (*ptr) & bitSign) ) ;
  }

}
```

First, why is starting at bit 32, even though I only shifted by one bit?

Second, is it ok for me to check the 64th bit of a `double` to check its sign on MSVC++?

Comment: Oh and please don't answer `if( (x < 0 && y < 0) || (x > 0 && y > 0) ) puts( "same" ) ; else puts ("different") ;`

Comment: have you thought about checking the sign of the product of x and y?
( x * y < 0 ) ? "different" : "same"

Comment: @falconcreek a multiply runs the risk of an overflow for large values

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At a minimum, there are three comparisons that -must- happen

1. extract sign of a
2. extract sign of b
3. compare a and b for equality

There's no way to avoid those three things.

You can do an `and`, you can do a `less than`, doesn't really matter which - you -probably- could find a cool/clever/tricky way to do it another way too. But you're still going to need to have those three elementary operations. There's also no need to overly complicate it. If you're looking for something to stick on one line, you could do this:

```
__int64 mask = 0x8000000000000000; // i think that's the right amount of 0's :-)
if( (x&mask) ^ (y&mask) ) 
  puts("different");
else
  puts("same");
```

Here I'm extracting the bit and xor'ing them. If the bit is the same, the xor will be 0 (false) - if the bits are different, the xor will be 1 (true). With a good comment explaining what you're doing and why, this is a perfectly valid way to do it.

HOWEVER: The example you gave as "don't use this" isn't really all that bad... It's easy to read, which is one of the most important things you can have in your code. There are two rules to optimization:

1. Don't do it.
2. (Experts only) Don't do it yet.

Don't sacrifice readability for optimization of something that's already pretty darned fast, and will probably be plenty fast enough. :-)

Answer (score 2):

In C++11, we were given [`std::signbit`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/signbit) that returns `true` if **negative**, and `false` otherwise.

Given two doubles, `a` and `b` we can compare their signs with `==` or `!=`:

```
void classify(double _lhs, double _rhs)
{
    std::cout << _lhs << " and " << _rhs;
    if (std::signbit(_lhs) == std::signbit(_rhs))
        std::cout << " have the same sign\n";
    else
        std::cout << " have different signs\n";
}
```

[Live Demo](https://wandbox.org/permlink/ZWtoJrQv3dFsDAxq)

---

`std::signbit` supports `double`, `float`, `long double`, and all integral types. It can even handle `NaN` values.

Answer (score 0):

```
((((__int64*)(&z))*) & 0x8000000000000000) give you the sign
```

Answer (score 0):

`double` does have a sign bit (the most significant bit), but finding the sign of a number is a bit more complicated than that.  Do you want to distinguish between +0.0 and -0.0?  Or between +NaN and -NaN?